# C++ , is this goto statement warranted?

Tags: c++, exception, goto

I have changed title slightly because I thought this is more appropriate question.

Would you refactor it (seems like legitimate use of goto) ?
If, how would you refactor the following code to remove go to statement?

```
if (data.device) {
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch(const std::exception&) { goto done; }
    ... // more things which should not be caught
done: ;
}
```

complete statement

```
#ifdef HAVE_GPU
            // attempt to use GPU device
            if (data.device) {
                try {
                    Integral::Gpu eri(S, R, Q, block.shell());
                    eri(basis.centers(), quartets, data.device);
                }
                // if GPU fails, propagate to cpu
                catch(std::exception) { goto done; }
                data.device += size;
                host_index.extend(block_index);
                block_index.data.clear();
            done: ;
            }
#endif
```

thank you

after have seen preference of most, I decided to go with flag, but with Mr. York comment.

Thank you everybody

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what's in the blocks, but another possibility is to move the code within the if to a function. (Might improve readability too, maybe not.) Then you can just return early if something bad happened.

Comment: Catch by const reference, please.

Comment: @GMan added complete statement.  Function may be overkill, since there is no closure.

Comment: Looking at te code you added, is it not interesting elsewhere that you are using the GPU or the CPU? If so, you have a natural control flag.

Comment: Now my only question is: can the `.extend` and `.clear` methods throw?

Comment: @Neil this particular code path should execute on GPU, but GPU is not able to handle all input, therefore if it fails, it fals back to cpu.

@GMan extend can throw if there is really serious problem and program should terminate

Comment: @aaa: Hm, okay. Too bad, then the solution would be simple. :) EDIT: Scratch that, maybe it still can be. I assume it throws `bad_alloc` if it fails? (`extend`)

Comment: @GMan yes, unfortunately GPU may also throw that, so I am little worried to catch bad allocation.  I think I will go with status flag, seems like simplex thing after go to

Comment: @aaa: Sure. I think Steve's flag is best. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if (data.device)
{
    bool status = true;

    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(std::exception)
    {
        status = false;
    }

    if (status)
    {
    ... // more things which should not be caught
    }
}
```

Comment: may be somewhat obvious answer, but which would you prefer? Status or goto?

Comment: @aaa: I may not be the best person to ask since I'm an unrepenting antigotoite.  :-)  Earlier today I was downvoted for answering a question with "Here's how you'd do it without goto: ..."  But my reasons have more to do with scalability and orthogonality than just a dislike for the keyword.

Comment: Why do people insist on introducing new variables and branches just to avoid a goto? Stop drinking the kool aid of "Considered Harmful" papers (better yet, actually read the paper and you'll see Dijkstra doesn't save never use them) and actually put for some critical thinking about what you're doing. You've added more state and more branches to your code just to satisfy "I didn't use `goto`."

Comment: Rather than set status = true. I would set status = false as the initial state. Then as the last statment inside the true set status = true thus it is false unless it makes it all the way through the try block without thorwing.

Answer (score 8):

First: goto isn't evil per se. Refactoring for the pure sake of not having the letters "goto" in your code is nonsense. Refactoring it to something which gets the same thing done cleaner than a goto is fine. Changing a bad design into one which is better and doesn't need a goto or a replacement for it is fine, too.

That being said, I'd say your code looks exactly like what finally was invented for. Too sad C++ doesn't have something like this... so maybe the easiest solution is to leave it like that.

Comment: Hell yeah! Go goto! go go go! to!

Comment: Unfortunately finally() is not the correct solution here as the code is only used when there is no exception, finally on the other hand means that it should always be executed (even when exceptions are present). Though finally is required for languages like C# and Java it is not required for C++ as there are better techniques for implementing the same thing. Though I agree with all your other points. Don't fix what is not broken.

Comment: @Martin York is right. That part was nonesense, now I wonder how I got that idea o.O
@sdeer: Wow, that's a... interesting reason for +1,  but considered the grammar and wording of some fellas, I can understand it.

Answer (score 7):

You can catch the exception and rethrow a specific exception that can be handled outside of the conditional block.

```
// obviously you would want to name this appropriately...
struct specific_exception : std::exception { };

try {
    if (data.device) {
        try {
            // ...
        }
        catch(const std::exception&) { 
            throw specific_exception(); 
        }

        // ... more things which should not be caught ...
    }
}
catch (const specific_exception&) { 
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: thank you.  I have thought about it but it adds more complexity in my opinion than goto/flag

Comment: @aaa:  This is, in my opinion, far cleaner than either of those options.  A `goto` is entirely unwarranted in this case, and if you use a status flag you end up mixing two different failure reporting mechanisms (status flags and exceptions) in a single block of code, which greatly increases complexity and makes it more difficult to reason about the code.

Comment: What is the meaning of *goto is warranted/unwarranted*? The behavior of `goto` is well defined and (I believe) will do what you would expect, or will it not? I agree that adding a bool check is *not* the way to go anyway.

Comment: @David:  Well, I was subconsciously using the OP's word "unwarranted" to express that I wouldn't use `goto` in this scenario.  While the `goto` would probably work in this scenario (I have to admit, I've not written a `goto` in C++ code, ever), I don't think a nested try/catch block adds much complexity and it makes the intent of the code clearer (because there is exactly one error handling mechanism being used--exceptions).

Comment: I think is far worse than the original use of goto. The status answer above is so much cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Why not move the extra code inside the try block?:

```
#ifdef HAVE_GPU
            // attempt to use GPU device
            if (data.device) {
                try {
                    Integral::Gpu eri(S, R, Q, block.shell());
                    eri(basis.centers(), quartets, data.device);
                    data.device += size;
                    host_index.extend(block_index);
                    block_index.data.clear();
                }
                // if GPU fails, propagate to cpu
                catch(std::exception) { /* handle your exception */; }
            }
#endif
```

Comment: OP's code made clear, that the first two lines contain a rated break point which is allowed to throw. Your example would swallow every exception. `host_index.extend()` is now allowed to fail silently.

Comment: Basically your saying, put the minimal amount of code inside of a try block as possible?

Comment: If he made that clear, it wasn't in the question. Note the comment "handle your exception" within the catch. It's up to the OP to write that code.

Answer (score 4):

I think a variant of this might work for you.

```
// attempt to use GPU device
if (data.device)
{
    try
    {
        Integral::Gpu eri(S, R, Q, block.shell());
        eri(basis.centers(), quartets, data.device);

        data.device += size;
        host_index.extend(block_index);
        block_index.data.clear();
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc&)
    {
        // this failure was not because 
        // of the GPU, let it propagate
        throw;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // handle any other exceptions by
        // knowing it was the GPU and we 
        // can fall back onto the CPU.
    }
}

// do CPU
```

If you could edit the GPU library and give all GPU exceptions some base like `gpu_exception`, the code becomes much simpler:

```
// attempt to use GPU device
if (data.device)
{
    try
    {
        Integral::Gpu eri(S, R, Q, block.shell());
        eri(basis.centers(), quartets, data.device);

        data.device += size;
        host_index.extend(block_index);
        block_index.data.clear();
    }
    catch (const gpu_exception&)
    {
        // handle GPU exceptions by
        // doing nothing and falling
        // back onto the CPU.
    }

    // all other exceptions, not being 
    // GPU caused, may propagate normally
}

// do CPU
```

If nether of these work, I think the next best thing is [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345994/c-is-this-goto-statement-warranted/3346232#3346232).

Answer (score 4):

Slightly different use of a flag. I think it's neater than Amardeep's.

I'd rather use a flag to indicate whether to propagate the exception, than a flag to indicate whether the last thing worked, because the *entire point* of exceptions is to avoid checks for whether the last thing worked -- the idea is to write code such that if we got this far, then everything worked and we're good to continue.

```
#ifdef HAVE_GPU
    // attempt to use GPU device
    if (data.device) {
        bool dont_catch = false;
        try {
            ...
            dont_catch = true;
            ... // more things which should not be caught
        } catch (...) {
            if (dont_catch) throw;
        }
    }
#endif
```

Comment: @GMan: change made - it's different behaviour to the questioner's code, of course, but it saves an argument over value vs reference ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (data.device) {
    bool ok = true;
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch(std::exception) { ok = false; }

    if(ok) {
        ... // more things which should not be caught
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you not catch the exception outside the if?

Comment: other logic would make it very ugly, so I would rather not

Answer (score 2):

When there is a bunch of code that needs to exit based on some condition, my preferred construct is to use a "do {} while(0)" loop and "break" when appropriate.  I don't know what break; will do in a catch, though.  A "goto" might be your best bet if "break" won't work.

Comment: That is worse than a `goto` in every way.

Comment: +1 That is just as bad as the `goto`, but better than adding an extra variable and having to add conditions in the code. And I am inclined to think that either of these are better than throwing a new exception type... I still prefer the `goto`, but heck this answer deserves no less than the others :)

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something, or wouldn't it be equivalent to move the part between the `catch` and `done:` label inside the `try` block?

```
#ifdef HAVE_GPU
            // attempt to use GPU device
            if (data.device) {
                try {
                    Integral::Gpu eri(S, R, Q, block.shell());
                    eri(basis.centers(), quartets, data.device);
                    data.device += size;
                    host_index.extend(block_index);
                    block_index.data.clear();
                }
                // if GPU fails, propagate to cpu
                catch(std::exception) {}
            }
#endif
```

Comment: +1: *If* this is what the OP wants to do, it's the simplest solution.

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. Now if anything that was outside the try before throws, its exception just gets eaten.

Answer (score 1):

What about just using some flag and adding a conditional statement?

```
int caught = 0;
if (data.device) {
    try {
        /* ... */
    } catch (std::exception e) { caught = 1; }
    if (!caught) {
        // more stuff here
    }
    // done: ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have something against the `bool` type?

Answer (score 1):

```
catch(std::exception) { return; }
```

That should do the trick.  I am, of course, assuming that `done` is indeed at the end of a function.

If you need to execute additional code when the exception occurs, return a status or throw an exception that is at a more proper level of abstraction (see James' answer).

I'm imagining something like:

```
doStuff(...) {
    bool gpuSuccess = doGPUStuff(...);
    if (!gpuSuccess) {
        doCPUStuff(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: And skips everything else in the function.

Comment: Which may well be the right thing to do, or at least to refactor to.

Comment: I don't think `done:` is currently the end of a function - it's followed by the code to use the CPU rather than the GPU (which must either have failed or been compiled out).

Comment: @Steve: Probably true.  I'd likely use more than one function for this, otherwise follow James McNellis' approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just break it out into its own function/method (including everything after it) and use the `return` keyword.  As long as all your variables have destructors, are stack-allocated (or smart-pointered if unavoidable), then you're fine.  I'm a big fan of early-exit functions/methods rather than continual flag-checking.

for example:

```
void myFunc()
{
    String mystr("heya");
    try
    {
        couldThrow(mystr);
    }
    catch(MyException& ex)
    {
        return; // String mystr is freed upon returning
    }

    // Only execute here if no exceptions above
    doStuff();
}
```

This way, it's hard to go wrong

Comment: Agreed. Just put it in a function, and return when you want to, well, return.

Answer (score 1):

The reason goto is frowned on today is that we have these fancy things called "functions" instead. Wrap the GPU code in its own function, which can return early if it fails.

Then call that from your original function.

Since they'll probably need to share a few variables (`data`, `host_index` and `block_index`, it looks like), put them in a class, and make the two functions members of it.

```
void RunOnGpu(){
        // attempt to use GPU device
        if (data.device) {
            try {
                Integral::Gpu eri(S, R, Q, block.shell());
                eri(basis.centers(), quartets, data.device);
            }
            // if GPU fails, propagate to cpu
            catch(std::exception) { return; }
            data.device += size;
            host_index.extend(block_index);
            block_index.data.clear();     
}
void DoStuff() {
#ifdef HAVE_GPU
    RunOnGpu();
#endif
}
```